# SearchRequest in RootDSE

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I have to following function to query users from an AD server:

```
public List<LDAPUserDTO> getUsersWithPaging(String filter)
{
    List<LDAPUserDTO> userList = new ArrayList<>();

    try(LDAPConnection connection = new LDAPConnection(config.getHost(),config.getPort(),config.getUsername(),config.getPassword()))
    {
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("", SearchScope.SUB,filter, null);          
        ASN1OctetString resumeCookie = null;
        while (true)
        {
            searchRequest.setControls(
                    new SimplePagedResultsControl(100, resumeCookie));
            SearchResult searchResult = connection.search(searchRequest);
            for (SearchResultEntry e : searchResult.getSearchEntries())
            {
                LDAPUserDTO tmp = new LDAPUserDTO();
                tmp.distinguishedName = e.getAttributeValue("distinguishedName");
                tmp.name = e.getAttributeValue("name");
                userList.add(tmp);
            }

            LDAPTestUtils.assertHasControl(searchResult,
                    SimplePagedResultsControl.PAGED_RESULTS_OID);
            SimplePagedResultsControl responseControl =
                    SimplePagedResultsControl.get(searchResult);
            if (responseControl.moreResultsToReturn())
            {
                resumeCookie = responseControl.getCookie();
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }       
        return userList;
    } catch (LDAPException e) {
        logger.error(e.getExceptionMessage());
        return null;
    }


}
```

However, this breaks when I try to search on the RootDSE.

What I've tried so far:

```
baseDN = null
baseDN = "";
baseDN = RootDSE.getRootDSE(connection).getDN()
baseDN = "RootDSE"
```

All resulting in various exceptions or empty results:

```
Caused by: LDAPSDKUsageException(message='A null object was provided where a non-null object is required (non-null index 0). 

2020-04-01 10:42:22,902 ERROR [de.dbz.service.LDAPService] (default task-1272) LDAPException(resultCode=32 (no such object), numEntries=0, numReferences=0, diagnosticMessage='0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100213, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    ''
 ', ldapSDKVersion=4.0.12, revision=aaefc59e0e6d110bf3a8e8a029adb776f6d2ce28')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I really spend a lot of time with this. It is possible to kind of query the `RootDSE`, but it's not that straight forward as someone might think.

I mainly used WireShark to see what the guys at [Softerra](https://www.ldapadministrator.com/) are doing with their LDAP Browser.

Turns out I wasn't that far away:

[image: Wireshark Dump]

As you can see, the `baseObject` is empty here. 
Also, there is one additional Control with the OID [`LDAP_SERVER_SEARCH_OPTIONS_OID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/782fa852-2aef-42cd-b3d7-3f7a85861289)  and the ASN.1 String `308400000003020102`.

So what does this `308400000003020102` more readable: `30 84 00 00 00 03 02 01 02` actually do?

First of all, we decode this into something, we can read - in this case, this would be the `int 2`.

In binary, this gives us: `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0`

As we know from the documentation, we have the following notation:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30    | 31    |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|-------|-------|
| x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | x  | SSFPR | SSFDS |
```

or we just take the int values from the documentation:

- `1` = `SSFDS` -> `SERVER_SEARCH_FLAG_DOMAIN_SCOPE`
- `2` = `SSFPR` -> `SERVER_SEARCH_FLAG_PHANTOM_ROOT`

So, in my example, we have `SSFPR` which is defined as follows:

> For AD DS, instructs the server to search all NC replicas except
>   application NC replicas that are subordinate to the search base, even
>   if the search base is not instantiated on the server.  For AD LDS, the
>   behavior is the same except that it also includes application NC
>   replicas in the search.  For AD DS and AD LDS, this will cause the
>   search to be executed over all NC replicas (except for application NCs
>   on AD DS DCs) held on the DC that are subordinate to the search base.
>   This enables search bases such as the empty string, which would cause
>   the server to search all of the NC replicas (except for application
>   NCs on AD DS DCs) that it holds.

`NC` stands for `Naming Context` and those are stored as `Operational Attribute` in the `RootDSE` with the name `namingContexts`.

The other value, `SSFDS` does the following:

> Prevents continuation references from being generated when the search
>   results are returned. This performs the same function as the
>   LDAP_SERVER_DOMAIN_SCOPE_OID control.

So, someone might ask why I even do this. As it turns out, I got a customer with several sub DCs under one DC. If I tell the search to handle referrals, the execution time is pretty high and too long - therefore this wasn't really an option for me. But when I turn it off, I wasn't getting all the results when I was defining the `BaseDN` to be the group whose members I wanted to retrieve.

Searching via the `RootDSE` option in Softerra's LDAP Browser was way faster and returned the results in less then one second.

I personally don't have any clue why this is way faster - but the `ActiveDirectory` without any interface of tool from Microsoft is kind of black magic for me anyway. But to be frank, that's not really my area of expertise.

In the end, I ended up with the following Java code:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("", SearchScope.SUB, filter, null); 
[...]
Control globalSearch = new Control("1.2.840.113556.1.4.1340", true, new ASN1OctetString(Hex.decode("308400000003020102")));

searchRequest.setControls(new SimplePagedResultsControl(100, resumeCookie, true),globalSearch);
[...]
```

The used `Hex.decode()` is the following: `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex`.

A huge thanks to the guys at Softerra which more or less put my journey into the abyss of the AD to an end.

Answer (score 1):

You can't query users from the RootDSE.

Use either a domain or if you need to query users from across domains in a forest use the global catalog (running on different ports, not the default 389 / 636 for LDAP(s).

RootDSE only contains metadata. Probably this question should be asked elsewhere for more information but first read up on the documentation from Microsoft, e.g.:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/where-to-search
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/rootdse

E.g.: namingContexts attribute can be read to find which other contexts you may want to query for actual users.

Maybe start with this nice article as introduction:

http://cbtgeeks.com/2016/06/02/what-is-rootdse/

Comment: Turns out were kind of right but there's an easy option for this to let the LDAP do the work for you - see my answer here. Thanks for your time and contribution :)